# How to ignore pymysql warnings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, pymysql

Consider this code:

```
import pymysql

db= pymysql.connect("localhost","root","","raspi")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO access(username)VALUES('hello')")
db.commit()
db.close()
```

when I run it I'll get this error:

```
C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:165: Warning: (1364,"Field'salt' doesn't have a default value")result = self._query(query)
```

How do I ignore pymysql warnings?

Comment: Set a default value for `salt`, be it empty, `null` or `banana`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reason why you're getting that error is because your `salt` field is not allowing NULL values but you're trying to insert them, probably your table creation sql code looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `access` (
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    ...
    `salt` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

If you just wanted to allow NULL values for that field maybe your SQL code would need to be change into something like:

```
...
`salt` VARCHAR(50) NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
...
```

Anyway, if you still insist to keep your original db structure and want to learn how filter out warnings, here's a possible way to you could do it:

```
import pymysql
import warnings


db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "raspi")

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO access(username)VALUES('hello')")
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

For more information, take a look to the [warnings docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings)